# Can an indefinite article be used with plural noun "units"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, adjective-phrases

In one of my network textbooks, a text is as:

> The difference is simply a constant 10 units for time greater than 2 seconds.

The article "a" does not seem to be fit with plural "units". Am I wrong? Should it be like:

> The difference is simply a constant **which/that is** 10 units for time greater than 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. The indefinite articles a is used to modify singular nouns. When using a plural noun, article 'a' is unnecessary. Plural nouns can take either a definite article or no article at all.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/ Yeah, you're wrong; the indefinite (not *infinite*) article is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot say *a units.*

You can say *a constant 10 units*, because you are talking about all 10 of those units as 1 indivisible thing.  The real noun is something like "a group of 10 units that remain constant."  Just like you can say *a bushel of apples* or *a bag of coins*.

Your second example doesn't work because you aren't just talking about a constant, but the full concept of "a constant 10 units."

Saying *a bag of coins* and *a bag which is containing 10 coins* very technically refers to the same thing, but *a bag which is containing 10 coins* makes it sound like you don't care about the coins at all and you really just want the bag.

Comment: Should your **a group of 10 units that remain constant** be **a group of 10 units that remains constant**?